# Closed Object allows some of the cut geometry to escape the cut

Tags: modeling

You'll notice in the attached image that some of the geometry is not cut by the rectangle/plane and extends beyond it, if it's fairly close to the cut (notice the red line in the left pic).  Why is that happening and is there a threshold I can set to prevent that?  Thanks

[image: Cut and not cut geometry]

Comment: no entiendo bien tu pregunta, puedes editarla para que sea mas explicita y poner una imagen de mejor calidad ? puedes tomar screenshot con `CTRL + F3`

Comment: The red rectangle in the right image is supposed to cut the black/orange geometry using Knife Project.  The image on the left is a close-up (notice the horizontal red line) of the upper edge of the rectangle.  Notice how the orange/selected geometry includes a couple of vertices that were not cut by the red edge and they should appear black.  I'm wondering why knife select fails to cut that part of the geometry that is close to the cutting edge.  Thanks

Comment: can you undo that step? It is very likely that you have a bad topology that also influences
you have already tried, in object mode you select the mesh press `ctrl` ** + **` A` and select scala and rotation. then enter the mesh and select all in faces and press `ctrl` ** + **` N` to adjust the normal outwards, and then try project knife